# em-websocket with private channels

Tags: ruby, websocket, publish-subscribe, eventmachine, em-websocket

I need to create a web-socket server, I am planning to use em-websocket. I need to support private channels, that is I should be able to send message to one particular channel or subscriber.

There are many good chat examples that are in broadcast mode ie. they send the response to all the connected clients but I need to track each connected client somehow, and respond to each one separately. In other way, I need one private channel for each client so that I can respond to each client separately instead of broadcasting to all connected ones, make each web-socket connection unique

Can anyone guide me to right direction for implementing this or may be some example or gist.

Regards.

Comment: I have found solution,
seems like I am not looking for "channels", as suggested by @igrigorik, I solve this by making WS connection unique, so I would just track that and send individual msgs.
[Gist here](https://gist.github.com/RohitRox/5369168)

Comment: Could you please explain it a little bit further? Thanks

Comment: Any code examples for this approach?

Comment: The gist https://gist.github.com/RohitRox/5369168